# How to fix leaky plastic to metal adapter?

Tags: plumbing

I have a drain pipe for my 2001 camper, that goes through the bottom of the camper.   Attached to the bottom of the plastic hose is a threaded female adapter that rotates 360 degrees:

[image: Leaky]
There is a small drip drip leaky that is coming from the adapter.  If I push up on it, the water comes out as a steady stream.  I'm not sure how the metal is attached to the plastic, but I'm assuming that i just need to cut the plastic  above the clamp? and purchase a new metal adapter.  I just have no idea, what that adapter would be called, and where to purchase it, and if there is a better way of taking the old one off, besides hacksawing the plastic pipe above the clamp?

Ideas?

Comment: I can't quite tell from this photo, but it doesn't look like PVC. As best as you can tell, what kind of plastic tubing is it?

Comment: @BrownRedHawk It's the original tubing that came with my camper 15 years ago... so whatever that would be...

Comment: Since this plastic tube has a crimp style clamp, I'd just take it apart and replace that with an adjustable stainless steel hose clamp.  These are tightened with a screwdriver or nut driver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a standard 3/4" pipe.  I was able to cut it off, and shark bite a new piece on.